# jQuery hover only working on left side of div

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-hover

I'm trying to code a top nav bar that only appears when hovering on the top of the page using jQuery hover(). I've gotten it to work succesfully but it only works when I hover on the left side of the nav bar, nothing happens on the right side of the page. When I inspect element the top bar is covering the whole page horizontally. Any ideas why this might be happening? Code below:

```
<div class="desktop-display">
    <div id="navigation-wrapper" class="navigation-wrapper">
        <header class="main-header" role="banner">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <a href="#">LINK</a>
                    <a href="#">LINK</a>  
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <img src="logo.jpg">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <a href="#">LINK</a>
                    <a href="#">LINK</a> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery( "#navigation-wrapper" ).hover(
        function() {
            $( this ).addClass( "nav-hover" );
        }, function() {
            $( this ).removeClass( "nav-hover" );
        }
    );
});
```

CSS:

```
.nav-hover {
    background-color:white;
    margin-bottom:79px;
}

.nav-hover .navigation a {
    color:black;
}
```

Comment: Your code is [working fine here](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/n8pyrsap/).

Comment: Without seeing the rest of the code (or a live preview) it's hard to discern why, because the code is valid. Could simply be due to an element covering the right side.

Answer (score 1):

just try this **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/1hqorezj/)**

I just made few changes,

**css**

```
.nav-hover .navigation a {
    color:black;
}
```

1. You dont have any ".navigation" class in your HTML code. so links were not getting black color.
2. so just add ".navigation" class with row.

rest you just check the code if it works for you. then use it.

```
<div class="row navigation">
    <div class="col-md-4"> 
        <a href="#">LINK</a>
        <a href="#">LINK</a> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <img src="logo.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <a href="#">LINK</a>
        <a href="#">LINK</a> 
    </div>
</div>
```